# C#. Можно ли сделать сортировку по переопределенному полю?

Tags: c#, linq

Есть такая модель:

```
 public class Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class People : Entity
    {
        public new string Name { get; set; }
    }
    
public class Customer : Entity
```

И общий метод для сортировки по `Name`

```
public static void SortByName(IEnumerable<Entity> Data)
{
    Data = Data.OrderBy(x => x.Name);

    foreach (var data in Data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data.Name);
    }
}
```

Если передать туда `IEnumerable<Customer>` - то сортировка пройдет нормально, а вот с `IEnumerable<People>` уже не выходит. Можно ли это как то учесть что если в наследнике есть переопределенное поле `Name` - то сортируем по нему?

Таких моделей как `People` может быть десяток, а метод всего лишь один

Comment: Вы знаете разницу между override и new операторами? (Между переопределением и сокрытием свойства)

Comment: И в чем смысл в наследнике перекрывать свойство с точно таким же поведением?

Comment: А если пометить Entity.Name как virtual и затем в People не new, а override, то будет сортироваться?!

Comment: @tym32167 теперь знаю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойство Name в классе People не переопределено. Оператор new всего лишь позволяет вам использовать существующее в базовом классе имя свойства для определения нового свойства в наследнике.

Чтобы использовать полиморфизм, необходимо объявить свойство Name в классе Entity с модификатором `virtual`, а свойство Name в классе People с модификатором `override`.

В противном случае, вам придется в функции keySelector делать проверку типа `x`, приводить его к конкретному типу (People) и возвращать свойство People.Name.